# Еще раз про кросс-доменный запрос

Tags: ajax

Имеется запрос, который отправляется на чужой сайт и передает значение переменной гетом через URL, чужой сайт про меня ничего не знает. Затем парсим контент из дива(то что в колбеке). После запроса success не выполняется, хотя в отладчике Хрома можно увидеть страницу, ругается на Unexpected token. Если допишу error зайдет в error после выполнения запроса.

```
function jsonp_callback(){
    $('#what_i_want').val();
}
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
    url: 'http://domen.ru/'+$('#my_input').val()+'.html',
   success: function (data) {
      alert('jsonp');
   }
});
```

Что не так делаю? читал доки и не до конца понял подходит ли в моем случает JSONP или нет, в том смысле, что ЧУЖОЙ сайт меня "не знает" и никакого JSON сервер не отдает мне.

Answer (score 2):

Запросы с клиента на другой домен запрещены политикой безопасности JavaScript.

Решение — обращаться с запросом на свой домен, где лежит прокси-скрипт, делающий запрос к удалённому ресурсу и возвращающий вам результат.

---

Новые версии браузеров допускают кроссдоменный запрос, но сервер при этом должен как вы сказали "знать" о вас и вернуть заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, в котором указан конкретный домен, либо`*`

---

```
$data=http_build_query($_POST);
$contx=stream_context_create(array('http'=>array(
    'method'=>'GET',
    'header'=>'content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'content'=>$data
)));
readfile("http://$_POST[addr]",false,$contx);
```

мною использовался такой код, для переброса `post` запроса на другой сервер.
Вы отправляеете `post` (можно и `get`) на скрипт, он его перебрасывает на $_POST['addr'] методом указанным в `$contx`. Соответсвенно в вашем AJAX-запросе должен быть указан параметр `addr`

Comment: если нужно могу предоставить такой на PHP

Comment: Да, с радостью посмотрю ваше решение

Comment: единственный минус метода в том что все запросы делаются через (обычно один) ip сервера, на котором стоит хост

Comment: вот-вот, я тоже задумался сколько запросов яндекс разрешит сделать, перед тем как забанить мой ip?!